# I need to make a sticky-state checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox

This code does what I want:

```
< input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"/>
```

except I would like to start out with the checkbox NOT checked.

Basically, I want the checkbox to start out as unchecked but then to change to checked when ticked AND THEN REMAIN AS CHECKED AFTER THE PAGE IS REFRESHED AND HENCEFORTH.

How can I modify this code to accomplish my needs?

Comment: Using dynamic link/webconfig, you send/get its value as an address parameter and set/get before user action.

Comment: Huseyin, thanks. I'm not a programmer, so your perspective is only partially comprehensible to me. Is it not possible to modify the code I quoted to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

This will allow your checkbox to "remember" if it was checked between page refreshes.

Use this javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                var cb = document.getElementById("thatonecheckbox");
                var isChecked = localStorage.getItem("thatonecheckbox").toLowerCase() == 'true';
                console.log(isChecked);
                if(isChecked == true)
                    cb.checked = true;
                else
                    cb.checked = false;
            }

            function cbClick(){
                var cb = document.getElementById("thatonecheckbox");
                localStorage.setItem('thatonecheckbox',cb.checked); 
            }
        </script>
        <input id="thatonecheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="cbClick();" onkeydown="cbClick();"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

You might also want to consider sessionStorage instead. This will not be shared across tabs and will delete the data when the tab is closed. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am editing a Wordpress blog in text mode. My objective is to create a To Do list on a posting that has functional checkboxes that will maintain their checked or unchecked status henceforth from whenever they are toggled one way or the other. The code you gave me above creates a CHECKED checkbox that can be unchecked but then refreshes as CHECKED again.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Same result: I can check the checkbox but it comes back after page refresh as unchecked.

Comment: What browser are you using? The latest version of what?

Comment: Latest version of Firefox as well as Safari. Does the code you gave me above work for you in the manner I am wanting?

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer. This should work great for you. Sticky checkbox with no server calls.

Answer (score -1):

The word CHECKED  - checks the box

so to start, use

```
 < input type="checkbox" />
```

and then add in CHECKED to have it checked

```
 < input type="checkbox" CHECKED/>
```

You will need to POST or GET the data onto the next page or to use a COOKIE/Database to keep its state, there is no way to just have it always checked with out passing that data on

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Here is what I have now...  

< input type="checkbox" UNCHECKED onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"/>  

...with the result being that the checkbox begins as unchecked and can be checked and unchecked but then when the page is refreshed, the checkbox is unchecked and cannot be clicked anymore. I want EXACTLY this behavior except that I want to checkbox to come back after a page refresh as CHECKED. How can I modify this code to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess I can't vote this up because I don't have sufficient reputation. Too bad, it was helpful... :(